# How to run captcha on local xampp server in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to run my project, which is in zf2, but image captcha is not working.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If we cant see your code, we cant tell you whats wrong.

Comment: To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your loaded PHP modules. If ZF2 uses GD or ImageMagic to generate images you have to enable them in your PHP configuration file.
On Windows:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll

php -m |find "gd"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Google reCaptcha form element, viewhelper and validator module for ZF2.

You can find it here if you are interested, https://github.com/krytenuk/recaptchav2.

Docs are also online [here](https://www.freedomwebservices.net/zend-framework/fws-recaptcha).